# How to create a detail page button that captures the record Id and it will trigger the lightning web component in a new App page

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-button, button

Lightning Web Components: How to create a detail page button that captures the record Id and it will trigger the lightning web component in a new App page. We need a solution that doesn't involve the aura component.

Comment: While using the aura component the view is displayed as a pop-up but not displayed on the record page or App page.

Answer (score 1):

To create a standard detail page button you will need to use an aura component as LWC does not have required interfaces like quick action,  isURLAddressable.

**Other option:**
You can also create a tab on your record page (next to details and related) and house the LWC there instead of a button

Comment: Thank you for your response. But while using the aura component the view is displayed as a pop-up but not displayed on the record page or App page.